# Unable to install GCC-4.9.0

Tags: gcc, makefile, installation, gcc4.9

I am trying to install gcc-4.9.0 locally. I gave the following command for configuring the install

```
LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/home/user/gmp-6.0.0/lib:/home/user/mpfr-3.1.2/lib:/home/user/mpc-
1.0.2/lib ./configure --prefix=/home/user/gcc-4.9.0-latest --with-
gmp=/home/user/gmp-6.0.0 --with-mpfr=/home/user/mpfr-3.1.2 --with-
mpc=/home/user/mpc-1.0.2 --enable-languages=c,c++ --disable-multilib
```

It configured without giving any errors and then when i do `make install`, i get the following error

```
gcc-4.9.0> make install
make[1]: Entering directory `/home/user/softwares/gcc-4.9.0/build/gcc-
4.9.0'
/bin/sh ./mkinstalldirs /home/user/gcc-4.9.0-latest /home/user/gcc-4.9.0-latest
/bin/sh: line 0: cd: host-x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/fixincludes: No such file or    
directory
make[1]: *** [install-fixincludes] Error 1
make[1]: Leaving directory `/home/user/software/gcc-4.9.0/build/gcc-4.9.0'
make: *** [install] Error 2
```

Can anyone help me solve this?

The machine is running RHEL 4 and the linux kernel is 2.6.9-67.ELsmp

EDIT: I found errors in the config.log file

```
configure:4970: checking whether g++ accepts -static-libstdc++ -static-libgcc
configure:4987: g++ -o conftest -g -O2   -static-libstdc++ -static-libgcc conftest.cpp    
>&5
g++: unrecognized option `-static-libstdc++'
conftest.cpp:11:2: #error -static-libstdc++ not implemented
configure:4987: $? = 1
configure: failed program was:
| /* confdefs.h */
| #define PACKAGE_NAME ""
| #define PACKAGE_TARNAME ""
| #define PACKAGE_VERSION ""
| #define PACKAGE_STRING ""
| #define PACKAGE_BUGREPORT ""
| #define PACKAGE_URL ""
| /* end confdefs.h.  */
|
| #if (__GNUC__ < 4) || (__GNUC__ == 4 && __GNUC_MINOR__ < 5)
| #error -static-libstdc++ not implemented
| #endif
| int main() {}
```

EDIT2:

I ran make and received the following errors

```
checking for x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu-gcc... /home/user/software/gcc-4.9.0/host-
x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/gcc/xgcc -B/home/user/software/gcc-4.9.0/host-x86_64-
unknown-linux-gnu/gcc/ -B/usr/local/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/bin/ -B/usr/local/x86_64-
unknown-linux-gnu/lib/ -isystem /usr/local/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/include -isystem 
/usr/local/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/sys-include
checking for suffix of object files... configure: error: in `/home/user/software
/gcc-4.9.0/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/libgcc':
configure: error: cannot compute suffix of object files: cannot compile
See `config.log' for more details.
make[2]: *** [configure-stage1-target-libgcc] Error 1
make[2]: Leaving directory `/home/user/software/gcc-4.9.0'
make[1]: *** [stage1-bubble] Error 2
make[1]: Leaving directory `/home/user/gcc-build/gcc-4.9.0'
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

Comment: The "errors" in the first edit are not significant. The configure script is probing the compiler to see what it can do (and when it can't do something, it throws an error which gets into the log). You only need to worry if the configure script itself throws an error.

Comment: LD_LIBRARY_PATH should also be in the environment for make, I don't think configure records it.

Comment: `make clean` and then try again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you built all of the dependencies outside of the gcc packaging. Included is a script that will gather all of the dependencies into the gcc packaging and include them as part of the gcc build:

```
gcc-4.9.0/contrib/download_prerequisites
```

That should simplify your initial configuration.

Not sure what compiler and/or version being used to build the 4.9.0 gcc compiler. Assuming 3.4-ish if you are still on RHEL 4. Probably will need to build/install 4.2.x gcc in order to incrementally get the support required to build 4.9.x due to lack of pre-built gcc support for RHEL 4. It's the price of staying on an older platform.

Answer (score 0):

Two problems:

First, you should never build the compiler in the source directory. It might appear to work, sometimes, but it's not supported and the compiler developers don't do that, so you shouldn't. Create an external `obj` directory, and build there:

```
mkdir obj
cd obj
/path/to/src/configure ...blah...blah...blah
```

Second, you missed a step:

```
make
make install
```

I know lots of projects set up the makefile so that `make install` just works, but bootstrapping a compiler is a bit more complicated than most projects.

Comment: I added the output I received when i ran 'make' into the question itself as EDIT2

Comment: I spotted another problem, answer updated. Also, you should find the cause of the "cannot compile" in one of the config.log files. That's important.

Comment: I understood my mistake, of building the compiler from the source directory itself and now I am trying to do it from an object directory as you have suggested. Infact 'make' is running currently, let's see if it throws another error or not. I could not find any string as "cannot compile" in the log file though.

Comment: There's more than one `config.log`. It depends what directory was being configured when it failed.

Comment: facing the same issue. have done different directory, make and make install. anyone found any solutions on this?

Comment: @NaveenSharma Did you check the `config.log` files?

Comment: Yes, but as I said, those errors are not interesting. They're just configure detecting that it can't use a specific option. You need to track down the "cannot compute suffix of object files: cannot compile" in the `config.log`, and find out what it was trying to do. The OP seems incapable of doing so.

Comment: @ams, thanks. yea, i had checked that, but thought that might not be relevant since net activity was around static c++. `configure:4385: checking for suffix of executables
configure:4392: gcc -o conftest    conftest.c  >&5
configure:4396: $? = 0
configure:4418: result:
configure:4424: checking for suffix of object files
configure:4446: gcc -c   conftest.c >&5
configure:4450: $? = 0
configure:4471: result: o`. This is the only two times suffix is mentioned.

Comment: @ams, also, i also have a preexisting gcc 4.1.2 which might have its own deps and residuals. I have installed gmp, isl, mpfr, mpc in seperate prefixed locations though.

Comment: If your build is failing with that message then one of the `config.log` files must have the same error message and more details.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/60653/discussion-between-naveen-sharma-and-ams).